# Android static inner fragments and interfaces

Tags: android, android-fragments

From reading the Android docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html it seems that fragments should be a static inner class. It also seems that they should use an interface to communicate with activities. When I try to do both I get a cyclic dependency.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragment.Listener{
    // Activity methods

    @Override
    public void foo(){

    }

    static class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    interface Listener{
        public void foo();
    }
    // Fragment Methods
    }

}
```

Gives me a cyclic dependency error. What is the correct design to use?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it needs to be a static inner class, but it doesn't. you can (and probably should) define fragments in their own file

Comment: I got the idea that they should be static inner classes from reading the article I linked to. All of the examples explicitly show the static keyword, which only applies to inner classes. However, upon further reading outer classes are implicitly static, so perhaps they were just trying to be clear (which of course caused confusion).

Answer (score 1):

If the `fragment` is already an `inner class` then there is no need for the fragment to implement the `interface` just to communicate with the `activity`. You can directly communicate with your `MyActivity` inside the Fragment if it is an inner class.

If it is a separate class then you can implement an interface to communicated with the activity.

Comment: I had a typo in my example, the outer class should not have been static. Thus the static inner class cannot call it's (also non-static) methods.

Comment: @GDanger you cant make the class the extends Activity a static and also if you want to implement the inteface through a static way then you should create a new class for it

Comment: @GDanger opss my bad.. Yah you cant still implement a method that is inside a class, static or non-static, but you can call it inside the bracket of the class